# Laravel 5.4 change user role

Tags: php, laravel

I trying make changing role in my panel admin. But when i made it my form dont sending post request. Now only working showing user role. I cant fix it becouse when i click button to switch i dont get any error and role is not changing.

I use HttpRequester when i use url /admin/change its showing this error:
**MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233**

There is my code:

View:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h2>Panel Admina</h2>
<div class="panel-group">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Id</th>
      <th>Imię</th>
      <th>Nazwisko </th>
      <th>E-mail </th>
      <th>Nr.tele </th>
      <th>Użytkownik </th>
      <th>Moderator </th>
      <th>Admin </th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($users as $user)
  <tr>
    <form action="{{route('change')}}" method="post">

                {{ csrf_field() }}
      <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->lastname }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->email }}<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}"></td>
      <td>{{ $user->phonenumber }}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_user"/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Moderator') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_moderator"/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_admin"/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Przydziel rolę"></td>


    </form>
  </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Controller:

```html
  public function change(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();

        $user->roles()->detach();

        if ($request['role_user']) {
            $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());
        }
        if ($request['role_moderator']) {
            $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Moderator')->first());
        }
        if ($request['role_admin']) {
            $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first());
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Routing:

```html
Route::get('/admin', [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
        'middleware' => 'roles',
        'roles' => ['Admin']
    ]);

Route::post('/admin/change', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@change',
    'as' => 'change',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Admin']
]);
```

I really dont know how i can resolve my problem.

Comment: in your route try to remove the `middleware` and `rule` to see if that causes the problem

Comment: i do this and is still thats same

Comment: please try to put the post Route before the get one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to pass the user id to your route and your form action and instead of post make it put for example:

```
<form action="{{route('change', $user->id)}}" method="post">
```

and in your route:

```
Route::put('/admin/change/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@change',
    'as' => 'change',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Admin']
]);
```

and in your controller:

```
public function change(Request $request, $id)
```

Comment: still doesnt work;/  and i think id its not necessery becouse i use hidden email and its set uniqe

Comment: https://github.com/K3n0s/szpital/tree/paneladmina maybe thats will be better there is link to my github with this project

Comment: If you try to go to url by typing 'localhost:8000/admin/change' it will give you the error. it should happen through http request using a form. another thing i've noticed in your code your from doesn't submit any data but when i remove the table html code it the form is submitted correctly.

Comment: ye its work so really thx;p i must to figure how showing it ;p